# How can I make these formulas work with google forms so they reproduce into new entries?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a form that has these formulas do calculations for each entry. How to I make it so they do it for new entries?

```
=IF(AND(E2="Stfyc",G2<41),G2*0.49,IF(AND(E2="Stfyc",and(G2>40,G2<71)),G2*0.65,if(and(E2="Stfyc",and(G2>70,G2<101)),G2*0.77,if(and(E2="Stfyc",100<G2),0.94*G2,if(and(E2<>"Stfyc",G2<41),G2*1.2,if(and(E2<>"Stfyc",and(G2>40,G2<71)),1.45*G2,if(and(E2<>"Stfyc",and(G2>70,G2<101)),G2*1.8,if(and(E2<>"Stfyc",100<G2),2.1*G2))))))))

=IF(H2="30A",0,if(H2="2x30A",17,if(H2="50A",17,if(H2="2x50A",30,if(H2="100A",30,"")))))

=if(N2="","",N2-L2)

=if(O2="","",(J2+K2)*O2)
```

Comment: The formulas are now formatted as code (by perceding each line by four spaces), so it is clear where the actual line-breaks are; with standard formatting, lines become wrapped...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the special formula "arrayformula" that will allow you to set the formula on the first row of your document and it will be repeated for all the beneth rows.
here an exemple with the formula `=if(N2="","",N2-L2)`
With array formula it will be like: `=arrayformula(if(N2:N="","",N2:N-L2:L))`
the first 2 formulas you gave are a bit more complicated to encapsulate in an arrayformula (try to use named range for that)